# Why is a downloaded excel file "corrupted"

Tags: javascript, php, ms-office

I am working on a web application that downloads an excel report generated by an api. Running the call in postman returns a file that opens with no issues. Downloading it through the web application the file is corrupted and Excel was unable to fix it. If I open the irreparably corrupted file in notepad++ and save it without making any changes it is now corrupted but fixable by Excel. On top of that all three files are identical according to a hex editor.

EDIT: I do not have access to the API generating the excel, so I can not provide that code. For debugging purposes I am using a file on the server and the same issue is happening, so it appears to be somewhere on my side.
The intermediate api function is

```
function exportDebuggy($request, $fileSource)
{   
    $resData = array(
        "success" => false,
        "response" => array(),
        "message" => ""
    );

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $fileSource);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING , "");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $err = curl_error($ch);

    $code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);

    curl_close($ch);

    if ($err)
    {
        $resData['message'] = "cURL Error #:" . $err;
    }
    else if( $code === 401 )
    {
        $resData['message'] = "Client session has expired. Please re login.";
    }
    else
    {
        $resData = "";
    }

    return $resData;
}
```

and the js code that makes the call and handles saving is

```
function exportDebuggy()
{
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var endpoint = "/wp-json/data-tracker/exportDebug";

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
                if (xmlhttp.status == 200)
                {
                    var data = window.URL.createObjectURL(xmlhttp.response);
                    var link = document.createElement('a');
                    link.href = data;
                    link.download="transactionsDownloaded.xlsx";
                    link.click();
                }
                else if (xmlhttp.status == 400)
                {
                    alert('There was an error 400');
                }
                else
                {
                    alert('something else other than 200 was returned');
                }
            }
        };

        xmlhttp.open("GET", endpoint, true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', userID );
        xmlhttp.responseType = "blob";
        xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the code of your API that generates the Excel?

Comment: *"On top of that all three files are identical according to a hex editor"* ... this can't be possible, at least check the size, are they the same number of bytes ?

Comment: "_this can't be possible_" That is my thought as well, but they are, and the file size is identical as well. That is why I am so confused.